# Storing access token from a redirect url by an external api

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, spotify

I am using Spotify web api to make a web app using angular.

While I am able to authenticate the user and get playlists/tracks and even create playlists etc.., I am stuck on how to get access_token from redirect_url after user agrees with the scopes of my app.

Currently i am able to do the above by using the below code ...but it is a really bad and inefficient way.

Service.ts :

```
  // ASK USER TO GRANT PERMISSION FOR THE FOLLOWING SCOPES
  Login(showDialog = true) {
    const state = uuid();
    localStorage.setItem('xsrf-token', state);
    const params = {
      response_type: 'token',
      client_id: "ec540590bb6449a181edhjdjsdjkdshasbdjk",
      redirect_uri: "http://localhost:4200/selectionMenu",
      scope:
        'user-top-read%20user-read-private%20playlist-read-private%20user-library-modify%20playlist-modify-public%20user-follow-read%20user-read-playback-state%20user-modify-playback-state%20user-read-recently-played%20user-read-currently-playing%20user-follow-modify%20playlist-modify-private%20playlist-read-collaborative%20user-library-read%20user-read-email',
      state,
      show_dialog: `${showDialog}`
    }
    const redirectUrl = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?${qs.stringify(params)}`;
    window.location.href = redirectUrl;
  }
```

After this i am able to show the below screen:

[image]

After user activity [if he clicks on agree] spotify service will redirect to the following url:
`http://localhost:4200/selectionMenu`
but will append the access_token to the above url, so the final url to which my page will redirect to is as below:
`http://localhost:4200/selectionMenu#access_token=BQASUoH7jashdjakshdashvday63hvsjadjhqBEWmVi9bKNg7EBF7Dt2dCvSNWLlQ3zUOp6hGuLfvJ9QH4PXRLTz4AajPDyBW7SV9lXhFb_IF25qb7hheUsvyg7pX-zD-TsOtbRCb7ohF86wrjWGFRXuugT-mnWESBMCRVSxTi34nOcG4VpvM-Ew9F0kl1vq5zdsSRSnCvZwmsQNGngDVpj2rsS2nQG0EIXdqTmSut0CdZFFobz5k9ojpbw971ye5dl1cXnHlc&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&state=59418612-e4cb-46bb-90af-d01f7a2c790a`

Screen looks as follows:

[image]

To extract the access_token from the above url i am currently doing the following:

In Component.ts:

```
currentWindowUrl() {
    const pathname = new URL(window.location.href).pathname;
    const redirectURL = window.location.href.split('#');
    usableURL = redirectURL[1].split('&');
    this.getTokens();
  }

  getTokens() {
    const accessToken = usableURL[0].split('=')[1];
    const tokenType = usableURL[1].split('=')[1];
    const refreshTime = usableURL[2].split('=')[1];
    const state = usableURL[3].split('=')[1];
    // pass accessToken to service and store it.
    this.spotifyAuthorizeService.saveAccessToken(accessToken);
  }
```

I am basically using window.location.href and splitting it till I get access_token, which sound and is pretty lame.

**My Questions**

-> How do I get the access token appended to  redirect_url  by Spotify, In a better way and maybe store it in localStorage[Not good for xhr attacks] , Any other better way in which I can store it so that I can use it for every other page in my app and also refresh it after every 60 min [token expiry time].

-> Is there a way to not show the part after # in the url which is the access_token, so that I don't give it away.

**Angular-Auth-OIDC**

I have followed the documentation and came up with following configuration :

assets/auth.clientConfiguration.json:

```
{
    "stsServer": "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize",
    "redirect_url": "http://localhost:4200/selectionMenu",
    "client_id": "ec5405hgasfdhasfdashdgdcbd27987aef6",
    "response_type": "token",
    "scope": "user-top-read%20user-read-private%20playlist-read-private%20user-library-modify%20playlist-modify-public%20user-follow-read%20user-read-playback-state%20user-modify-playback-state%20user-read-recently-played%20user-read-currently-playing%20user-follow-modify%20playlist-modify-private%20playlist-read-collaborative%20user-library-read%20user-read-email",
    "post_logout_redirect_uri": "https://localhost:4200/",
    "start_checksession": true,
    "silent_renew": true,
    "silent_renew_url": "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize",
    "post_login_route": "/selectionMenu",
    "forbidden_route": "/forbidden",
    "unauthorized_route": "/unauthorized",
    "log_console_warning_active": true,
    "log_console_debug_active": true,
    "max_id_token_iat_offset_allowed_in_seconds": 10
}
```

And i ng serve the app following error pops up:

[image]

And when i click login, app redirects to below url:
`https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/.well-known/openid-configuration`

And ends up with a 405 error.

**MY UNDERSTANDING**

I know the url is wrongly configured, i am not sure what url to specify in stsServer, I guess it's spotify's url cause it provides the token service but i am not sure if the url i configured in the json file is correct.

Any insight in this would be helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

### Authenticate with third party authentication providers

Authenticating your client directly with a third party authentication providers is always a bad idea.

Instead you should setup a backend to hold this authentication, your client will not hold access tokens of third party auth providers but of your backend.

Here is a schema of how your authentication flow should looks like
[image]

### Retreiving the credentials

#### Javascript

You can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) which will do the perfect job you need to play with the URL parameters.

```
getTokens() {
  var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  return {access_token: urlParams.get("access_token"), refresh_token: urlParams.get("refresh_token")}
}
```

#### Angular

Angular provide a way to play with the URL dynamically with the [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute).

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.route.paramMap.pipe(params => {
    this.yourservice.saveToken(params.get("access_token"), params.get("refresh_token"))
  })
}
```

> Theses are examples and will maybe not match with your code or your context.

#### Tools

Here is a list of libraries you can use to achieve your goal :

1. [Symfony OAuth2 Client](https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle)
2. [Node OAuth2 Client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-oauth2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use OIDC Client for that purpose for providing authentication token from your own identity server.
There are two angular libraries I will suggest to use:

NG OIDC Client - https://github.com/sourcenetwork/ng-oidc-client

Angular Auth OIDC Client - https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client

You can achieve the following based on your question:

1. Refresh tokens on regular intervals ( defined by you)
2. Access token directly in code wherever you want
3. Store token in Session Storage or Local Storage based on your
   strategy.
4. Delete token whenever you want from a browser.

You won't have to do a manual process that you are doing right now with Spotify services.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I tried with Angular Auth OIDC Client approach and encountered a few troubles, i have updated in the post, Any insight would be helpful, thank you!

Comment: @BHARATHCHANDRA there are similar issues opened for the same library and yes I faced similar issues when it came to using the angular auth library. The reason was the config file was not loading properly plus Angular versions. To Fastrack your work, I would suggest to directly download their project. I did this, https://github.com/sourcenetwork/ng-oidc-client and ran it directly by running npm install. This ng-oidc-client using Identity Sample Server. Then you can pick similar approach by taking required code and do it.

Comment: This is working link for angular auth oidc client : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auth-oidc-client